# Accessing `Request` body parameters

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to create a chain of requests to third-party API with the following code:

```
import Vapor

final class APIController: RouteCollection {

    private let baseULR = "..."

    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        router.post("login", use: validate)
    }

    func validate(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
        // Get the phone number of the user
        let phoneNumber = try req.content.syncGet(String.self, at: "phone_number")
        return try req.client().post("\(baseUrl)/...", beforeSend: { post in
            try post.content.encode(json: ["phone_number": phoneNumber])
        })
    }
}
```

But when testing request, I'm getting an error:

```
[ ERROR ] Abort.415: Unsupported Media Type (ContentCoders.swift:95)
[ DEBUG ] Suggested fixes for Abort.415: Register an `DataDecoder` using `ContentConfig`. Use one of the decoding methods that accepts a custom decoder. (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)
```

That, unfortunately, I don't understand how to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to provide a `Content-Type` of a payload

```swift
func validate(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
    // Get the phone number of the user
    return req.content.get(String.self, at: "phone_number").flatMap { phoneNumber in
        return try req.client().post("/...") {
            try $0.content.encode(["phone_number": phoneNumber], as: .json)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also trying to access some of the custom header that I'm passing around, would this work for them?

Comment: You mean that you'd like to get some Header value from original request and put it into that new post request? If so then you may do it like that


    if let someValue = req.http.headers["someKey"].first {
        $0.http.headers.add(name: "someKey", value: someValue)
    }

Answer (score 1):

Vapor 3:

add code to `public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws` function in `configure.swift` file

```swift
var contentConfig = ContentConfig()
//same to request content-type
contentConfig.use(decoder: URLEncodedFormDecoder(), for: .urlEncodedForm)
services.register(contentConfig)
```